# What's wrong, why is the "copy assignment operator" invoked right after "copy constructor"?

Tags: c++

**[NOTE: My first attempt to implement such class, so please, don't throw stones at me and please don't be rude. Be patient. Thanks.]**

So, I have written a custom MyString Class in C++.

Running version can be found here: https://onlinegdb.com/rJMEzP9aD.

I got some strange behaviors. I am trying to get the `copy constructors`, `copy operator` and the `const char* data()` to work together.

EDIT #4: This is strange,

[image]

---

```
class MyString {
public:
        MyString(): pSize{0}, pStr{nullptr} {}
        
        MyString(const char* cstr): 
        pSize{compute_length(cstr)}, pStr{nullptr} 
        {
            pStr = new char[pCapacity];
            std::copy(cstr, cstr + pSize, pStr);
        }
        
        MyString(const MyString& rhs): 
        pSize{rhs.size()}, pStr{nullptr}
        {
            pStr = new char[pCapacity];
            std::copy(rhs.data(), rhs.data() + rhs.size(), pStr);
        }
        
        ~MyString()
        {
            if(pStr){
                delete[] pStr;
            }
        }
        
        size_t size() const { return pSize; }
        size_t capacity() const { return pCapacity; }
        const char* data() const { return pStr; }
        
        MyString& operator=(const MyString& rhs){
            if(this == &rhs)
                return *this;
            
            if(pCapacity < rhs.size()){
                delete[] pStr;
                pSize = rhs.pSize;
                pCapacity = (pCapacity < rhs.capacity()) ? rhs.capacity() : pCapacity;
                pStr = new char[pCapacity];

                std::copy(rhs.data(), rhs.data() + rhs.size(), pStr);
                return *this;
            }
            
            pSize = rhs.size();
            pCapacity = rhs.capacity();
            std::copy(rhs.data(), rhs.data() + rhs.size(), pStr);
            
            return *this;
        }
        
private:
    size_t pSize;
    char* pStr;
    size_t pCapacity = 14;
    
    inline size_t compute_length(const char* cstr)
    {
        if(cstr == "")
            return 0;
        
        size_t i = 0;
        while(cstr[++i] != '\0');
        return i;
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp,**

```
int main()
{
    MyString s("Hello");
    //assert(s == "Hello");
    
    cout << s << endl;
    s = "";
    cout << s << endl;
    assert(s == "wow");
    return 0;
}
```

This class supports what a regular String class supports, NOT everything, and obviously far from perfect. However, there's a `const char* data() const`; which returns a pointer. So, in case the previous class modifies the content of its pointer, the other pointer must also be affected. Like the STD class does. However, for my implementation this comes with some cost. Here I have no idea currently why I have the issues I have. For example: performing s = "something new";, doesn't seem to replace previous. Or, copy/move to previous allocated memory pointer e.g. when sizes of a string and local heap allocated string match vice versa.

Comment: Why do you think `s` should have `"wow"` in it? It looks like it should be empty.

Comment: `if(cstr == "")` You are comparing two pointers here.  You are probably trying to compare the strings that are pointed to, not the pointers themselves.  This is probably what is causing your core dump.

Comment: `pStr = new char[pCapacity];` your capacity is ***always*** 14. You never update it (except in the assignment op). Is this intentional? Also where is your overload of the `cout` output operator?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, exactly. But, not sure why it's happening. "Strange Behaviour"

Comment: There are multiple bugs in the shown code. This is what happens when a huge pile of code is written first, then an attempt is made to see if everything works. With multiple bugs, figuring out what's wrong is geometrically more complex. This program should be completely scrapped and rewritten from scratch, a few lines at a time, and only after testing and verifying that the first handful of lines of code are working correctly, the next handful of lines get written, and tested next.

Comment: @scohe001, the part about that, is only here for now. I will add resize and other functionality. I am trying to understand the shallow, deep, pointer issues here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I tried that. That's why I ended up posting here.

Comment: So if you "tried that", then after adding which lines of code did all the problems start? Because that must be the problematic lines of code, then.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I have simply changed the lines, but, the issue continues. I am not exactly sure. Maybe, I sould make a copy of the previous pointer, before I delete. Or, simply just modify the previous pointer if the sizes between string in and the local on the heap match. Without losing the pointer location. But, I am not sure that this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: No, that's not what you said before. I first wrote that what you should've done is write only a few lines at a time, ***test*** what's written to make sure it works correctly, then write more code. Then, when your testing fails you know exactly where the problem is. I did not say that "well, when something doesn't work just change a few lines of code in osme way and try again". Again: there are too many bugs in the shown code and it should simply be rewritten from scratch, properly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, relax mate. I don't see the bugs currently, which is yet another reason for why I posted here. I have rewritten this class a couple of times before. It used to look a lot uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes

1. Always store the string null terminated. It'll help interacting with other APIs.
2. Two friends added for `std::ostream` and `==`.
3. Memory cleanup.
4. Capacity always set to largest allocation seen during the class lifetime.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class MyString {
public:
   MyString() : MyString(""){}

   MyString(const char* cstr):
      pSize{compute_length(cstr)}, pStr{new char[pSize+1]}, pCapacity{pSize}
   {
      std::copy_n(cstr, pSize + 1, pStr);
   }

   MyString(const MyString& rhs):
      pSize{rhs.size()}, pStr{new char[pSize+1]}, pCapacity{pSize}
   {
      std::copy_n(rhs.data(),  rhs.size()+1, pStr);
   }

   ~MyString()
   {
      delete[] pStr;
   }

   size_t size() const noexcept{ return pSize; }
   size_t capacity() const noexcept{ return pCapacity; }
   const char* data() const noexcept{ return pStr; }
   char* data() noexcept { return pStr; }

   MyString& operator=(const MyString& rhs){
      if(this == &rhs)
         return *this;

      pSize = rhs.size();

      if(pCapacity < rhs.size()){
         delete[] pStr;
         pStr = nullptr;
         pStr = new char[pSize+1];
         pCapacity = pSize;
      }

      std::copy_n(rhs.data(), rhs.size() + 1, pStr);
      return *this;
   }
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyString& string)
   {
      os.write(string.pStr, string.size());
      return os;
   }
   friend bool operator==(const MyString& lhs, const MyString& rhs)
   {
      return std::strcmp(lhs.pStr, rhs.pStr) == 0;
   }

private:
   size_t pSize{};
   char* pStr{};
   size_t pCapacity{};

   static inline size_t compute_length(const char* cstr)
   {
      size_t i = 0;
      while(cstr[i] != '\0')++i;
      return i;
   }
};

int main()
{
   using std::cout;
   using std::endl;
   
   MyString s("Hello");
   assert(s == "Hello");

   cout << s << endl;
   s = "wow";
   cout << s << endl;
   assert(s == "wow");
   return 0;
}
```